# Shape Error in Tensorflow

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I am just trying to assign value to a placeholder but i m am getting error:Cannot feed value of shape () for Tensor 'image_input_22:0', which has shape '(1, 51, 51, 64)'

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
res=np.random.random([1,51,51,64])
image=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[1,51,51,64],name="image_input")
reshaped_image=tf.reshape(image,[1,51,51,64])
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
res=0
with tf.Session() as sess:
 sess.run(init)
 res=sess.run(reshaped_image,feed_dict={image:res})
```

Answer (score 3):

You reinitialized res to 0, which is a scalar, hence the error.